# how to create regex function to select an extract a query?

Tags: regex, validation

I'm trying to extract a query from a string, I tried writing my own function, but it doesn't match my needs totally.
What I need is:

`www.website.com/8056432988456?id=5`, I need `8056432988456`, with or without the `/` i.e. preceding a `?`.

This is the regex I made for it : `(?<=\/)(.*?)(?=\?)|(?<=\?)`

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Something like `(?<=\/)\d+(?=(?:\?.*)?$)`? See https://regex101.com/r/zWuXTJ/1. Or `(?<=\/)\d+(?=(?:\/?\?.*)?$)` (see https://regex101.com/r/zWuXTJ/2).

Comment: Why do you have `|(?<=\?)`? What do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: To be on the safe side: just in case you use JavaScript, this is more reliable approach: [URL.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname)

Comment: Did either of my suggestions work?

Comment: Yes it did ! It worked very well !! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?<=\/)\d+(?=(?:\/?\?.*)?$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zWuXTJ/2).

*Details*:

- `(?<=\/)` - there must be a `/` immediately on the left
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?=(?:\/?\?.*)?$)` - immediately on the right, there must be an optional occurrence of:

  - `(?:\/?\?.*)?` - an optional occurrence of an optional `/`, then `?` and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
  - `$` - end of string.